# Django: DRF relationship key issues

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am facing an issue while trying to create a model that another model has a foreign key to and each time an instance is created in the model the model that has a relationship to the model needs to update as well but I don't think this is a good way to create relationships

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  ....
  #three fields pointing to one model
  owner = models.ManyToManyField(School, verbose_name=_(
    "Ownes"), related_name='owner', blank=True)

  workes_at = models.ForeignKey(School, verbose_name=_(
    "Workes at"), related_name='Workes_at', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)

  learns_at = models.ForeignKey(School, verbose_name=_(
    "Learns at"), related_name='learns_at', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
```

this way I have the issue I talked about above as when I want to create a school instance the owner would need to be set on the user model
I also put the fields in the school model but that would mean when I want to filter users based on the schools they go to or own or work at, and also creating students or workers would be a hard task, I want to know what the recommended way to do this kind of stuff if maintaining 3 foreign key fields to the same model is not a good idea please recommend me another way, I have three types of user I have to handle in one model if that is not the best way tell me how are user types with different fields handled. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain more about your app?
like you have x type of users and model called x and this model has multiple users, so dive into your app so we can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 1 model with foreign key to user with role:

```
 class SchoolUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     SCHOOL_ROLES = (
         ("general", "General"),
         ("learn", "Learn"),
         ("owner", "Owner")
     )
     role = models.CharField(choices=SCHOOL_ROLES)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

user = User.objects.first()
school = School.objects.first()
school_user = SchoolUser()
school_user.user = user
school_user.school = school
school_user.role = 'learn'
school_user.save()

user = User.objects.first()
learns = user.schoooluser_set.filter(role='learn')
owners = user.schoooluser_set.filter(role='owner')
```

Comment: but when i create a school how would i make the user the owner of that school

Comment: that was my main issue

Comment: and also how would i know what student is in what school and which worker workes at which school

Comment: can you please clarify how this workes, it would be nice if you edited it in your answer

Comment: With my solution: user_instance.schooluser_set.filter(role="learn") this is query for all learner schools

Comment: but this means that i have to create schools and users through the schooluser model right?

Comment: Yes, you must create user and their role.